# How to give corner of table cell border the color of top/bottom border instead of the left/right border

Tags: css

is there a way to influence what color would be the corner pixel of a `div` (or in my case `th`) rendered, when the two neighboring sides of the corner have different colors?

It appears to me that no matter what I mark important or so the corner always gets the color of the side. But I would like to to use the border-top  color for the corner pixel.

Like in the following example to give the first row a continuous black border and separate the cells with the ugly red and the rest of the table to be simply grey.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

table tr td {
  border: 8px solid grey;
}

table tr:first-child {
  border: 8px solid black;
}

table tr th:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 8px solid red;
}

table tr:not(:first-child) td {
  border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
I want:
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> black-bordered </th>
    <th> row </th>
    <th> separated </th>
    <th> with </th>
    <th> reds </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> everything </td>
    <td> below </td>
    <td> it </td>
    <td> simply </td>
    <td> grey </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've also tried to remove the `border-collapse`, give a border to the `tr` element and a side border to the `th`s and set the `border-spacing` (which I just discovered) to zero. But the  `tr` border didn't show up at all and it messes the rest of the table (which could be fixed, though).

Comment: Not clear what you want. You want the top and side borders to be their own color, and then where they connect to be another color? Perhaps show an image of what you want.

Comment: No. I want the "where they connect" to be in the the top border color.

Comment: If you changed the `display` type to something like `inline-block` on your cells, the border colors would overlap correctly.

Comment: I have tried, and played with it for a bit now and it messes the table layout. Could you please try to answer with a snippet?

Comment: `inline-block` won't work, as all the cells are going to have width as much content there is, unless you put a fixed width (which will cause some cells to be too small or too big). The normal `table-cell` will adjust all cells in a column to the width of the largest. The same goes for a row.

Comment: Yeah I can't seem to get "adjust width to largest cell" to work with inline-block, so @pol still has the best solution. I just thought there would have been a way to combine the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them with a `pseudo element`, which will be the size of the whole `row + borders`. Then reapply only top and bottom border.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

table tr td {
  border: 8px solid grey;
  border-top: none;
}

table tr:first-child {
  border: 8px solid black;
}

table tr th:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 8px solid red;
}

table tr th {
  position: relative;
}

table tr th::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px; left: -8px;
  width: calc(100% + 16px); height: 100%;
  border-width: 8px 0;
  border-color: black transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
I want:
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> black-bordered </th>
    <th> row </th>
    <th> separated </th>
    <th> with </th>
    <th> reds </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> everything </td>
    <td> below </td>
    <td> it </td>
    <td> simply </td>
    <td> grey </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And what if I want to have the bottom line of the heading black too? I'm asking this because I suspect I'd soon run out of `:before`s and `:after`s.

Comment: remove the `border-top` on the second row of td's.

Comment: Ok. I've added the CSS rule to the question, could you please adjust your example? There is a need to sort other corners too and I thing in some cases there are three of them. Also this feels *really hacky* for such a simple thing...

Comment: I've readjusted. I've made the `:before` to put the top and bottom altogether. And yes, I know this is pretty hacky. I feel like there is another way, but can't think of another method right now.

Comment: Now you deserve a **holly cow** for the `calc()` function from me. I was actually thinking: *if I only could have size like 100% plus a few pixels*. Thank you!